# how i handle multi page app with data binding

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin.android, multipage

I am still a beginner in xamarin coding I try to build multi-page information app. i will use gridview for the first page contain title then second page its contain subtitle for each title in first page I try to use switch case with intent but it will make me build a lot of pages.cs and that is not effective for me. can anyone help me to find out more effective way or open source information app to understand how I build my app? I put my data in class like below

`class DataClass
    {
        public List mainpagelist()
        {
            List maingageinfo = new List();
            maingageinfo.Add(new MasterData("A"));
            maingageinfo.Add(new MasterData("B"));
            maingageinfo.Add(new MasterData("C"));
            maingageinfo.Add(new MasterData("D"));
            maingageinfo.Add(new MasterData("E"));
            maingageinfo.Add(new MasterData("F"));`

```
        return (maingageinfo);
    }

    public List<MasterData> A_Pages()
    {
        List<MasterData> A_Pagesinfo = new List<MasterData>();
        A_Pagesinfo.Add(new MasterData("A1"));
        A_Pagesinfo.Add(new MasterData("A2"));
        A_Pagesinfo.Add(new MasterData("A3"));
        A_Pagesinfo.Add(new MasterData("A4"));
        A_Pagesinfo.Add(new MasterData("A5"));
        A_Pagesinfo.Add(new MasterData("A6"));

        return (A_Pagesinfo);
    }

    public List<MasterData> B_Pages()
    {
        List<MasterData> B_Pagesinfo = new List<MasterData>();
        B_Pagesinfo.Add(new MasterData("B1"));
        B_Pagesinfo.Add(new MasterData("B2"));
        B_Pagesinfo.Add(new MasterData("B3"));
        B_Pagesinfo.Add(new MasterData("B4"));
        B_Pagesinfo.Add(new MasterData("B5"));
        B_Pagesinfo.Add(new MasterData("B6"));

        return (B_Pagesinfo);
    }

    public List<MasterData> C_Pages()
    {
        List<MasterData> C_Pagesinfo = new List<MasterData>();
        C_Pagesinfo.Add(new MasterData("C1"));
        C_Pagesinfo.Add(new MasterData("C2"));
        C_Pagesinfo.Add(new MasterData("C3"));
        C_Pagesinfo.Add(new MasterData("C4"));
        C_Pagesinfo.Add(new MasterData("C5"));
        C_Pagesinfo.Add(new MasterData("C6"));

        return (C_Pagesinfo);
    }
}</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand you correctly you want to have a list of pages that are stored in one master list. Then inside of the MainWindow display the master data list to select from using a switch then open another selection to make a new switch selection?

Sounds like its a basic information page which isn't to complicated...

there is a few ways to do what you want... but i would say the easiest is setup a basic design then use code behind to fill in the data and then only point to data and fill out the template..

```
        textboxName.Text = "information you want to fill in the area";
        textboxName.Height = 30;
        textboxName.Width = Double.NaN;
        textboxName.Name = "TextBoxName";
        textboxName.Background = Brushes.LightSkyBlue;
```

then instead of creating pages just pull data and load it into a basic structure from a list.

I hope that helps you should only have to build one page then.. load into different data

let me know if this works out for you..

Comment: can you bring me an open source app or link of a tutorial, also can i use for loop to get item position to make intent